# Can I use a pointer assignment to detect the start of a thread in a safe way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I quickly wrote some kind of wrapper to ensure some functionality in a system is always executed in a defined thread context. To make the code as small as possible, I simple use a pointer assignment to check if the thread has started.

```
void waitForStart() {
    while (_handler == nullptr) {
        msleep(100); // Sleep for 100ms;
    }
    msleep(100); // Sleep for 100ms to make sure the pointer is assigned
}
```

In my opinion, this should work in any case. Even if the assignment to `_handler` is for unknown reason split up into two operations on a CPU.

**Is my assumtion correct? Or did I miss a case where this could go wrong?**

For reference a more complete example how the system looks like. There are the `System`, the `Thread` and the `Handler` classes:

```
class Handler {
public:
    void doSomeWork() {
        // things are executed here.
    }
};

class Thread : public ThreadFromAFramework {
public:
    Thread() : _handler(nullptr) {
    }
    void waitForStart() {
        while (_handler == nullptr) {
            msleep(100); // Sleep for 100ms;
        }
        msleep(100); // Sleep for 100ms to make sure the pointer is assigned
    }
    Handler* handler() const {
        return _handler;
    }
protected:
    virtual void run() { // This method is executed as a new thread
        _handler = new Handler();
        exec(); // This will go into a event loop
        delete _handler; 
        _handler = nullptr;
    }
private:
    Handler *_handler;
}

class System {
public:
    System() {
        _thread = new Thread();
        _thread->start(); // Start the thread, this will call run() in the new thread
        _thread->waitForStart(); // Make sure we can access the handler.
    }
    void doSomeWork() {
        Handler *handler = _thread->handler();
        // "Magically" call doSomeWork() in the context of the thread.
    }
private:
    Thread *_thread;
}
```

Comment: You should use a [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) explicitely.

Comment: I considered this. This would prevent the CPU from reordering the memory access before and after the pointer access. Is this really necessary, just to make sure the `waitForStart()` method works? Why?

Comment: As you noticed the `_handler = new Handler();` isn't done atomically, neither is `while (_handler == nullptr)`. Thus you need to protect any reading or writing access with a mutex (or another suitable synchronization mechanism).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. So what can go wrong? In the worst case, the write operation is split up into two parts. E.g. the pointer is `0x00001234` - the while loop on the other thread exists, then  after a few ms it will change to `0x56781234`. But this is the reason why I added the additional `msleep(100)`. So after the `while` loop exits, there will be enough time to finish the write operation on the pointer. Or are I am completely wrong about this?

Comment: Why not avoid the problem altogether by creating the handler *before* starting the thread?

Comment: @Casey This would be the simplest way, but the handler has to be created in the thread context. I can not change the initialization of the handler, which is e.g. initialize COM, which has to be called in the context of the thread where it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a case where this can go wrong. The thread might exit 5 msec after it sets the pointer. Accessing any changing variable from two threads is never reliable without synchronization.

Comment: The thread will stay in the event loop after calling `exec()`. Therefore in this example, the thread will never exit, nor call `delete`. Just focusing on the `while` loop, can this go wrong? And why?